What kind of thread is on this gas BBQ?
I have a gas BBQ that is missing the nipple to attach the gas hose.

This is bought in Europe, and all the fasteners are metric, just this port has some weird dimensions.
The major diameter of the threads is 11mm (M11 or 7/16"), the thread pitch is 1.25 measured with a thread gauge (this corresponds to 20TPI).
The thread does not seem tapered, and NPT or BSP do not come in this dimensions anyway.

Take the fitting to a store/shop that does BBQs repairs/service or a plumbing/gas fitter shop.  Metric and standard are two different animals that do not match.  Might be close/similar but with gas is as bad as a horseshoe to the head.

Search the make and model on the web to identify the specific connector you need.  Major vendors like this should be able to supply it.  This is the only safe path to a solution.
Gas connectors worldwide have unique threads and shapes.  NPT, SPT, etc. will not mate with them; this is intentional to avoid mistakes.  Different gases have, in many cases, different connectors to prevent catastrophic errors (e.g., oxygen and nitrous oxide have different ; acetylene and oxygen welding hoses use the same connectors but left-hand and right-hand threads respectively).  Learn more about it here.

Standard 1/2” flared gas propane gas convert or transition to metric 12.7 mm.
